# Adding mfa verification code to ssh command?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, ssh

Im trying automate the login process using shell script.

I got MFA + pub key authentication working.

However Im stuck at how to pass verfication code as a parameter to ssh command.

I tried go through ssh pages and stuff but could not able to find.

For ex: ssh username@example.com -someoption verticationcode

Or if there is any way. Im more than happy to use it.

Comment: Typically one uses multi factor authentication to prevent automated logins... But maybe [`sshpass`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sshpass) might be of use there